# delete the duplicate record, and keep the one that has the lower id

Tags: sql

```
id  | MEMBER_BADGE_ID | MEMBER_ID
3127| 859986          | 2320
3128| 859986          | 2320
2461| 860058          | 1915
2545| 860062          | 1921
2546| 860062          | 1921
2460| 860063          | 1164
2468| 860064          | 1919
2469| 860064          | 1919 
2472| 860067          | 1921
2476| 860076          | 1923
2547| 860077          | 1930
2489| 860086          | 1930
2474| 860089          | 1922
2475| 860089          | 1922
2477| 8600102         | 1924
```

I would like to remove the duplicate row with the oldest ID in the whole table.

```
select id,MEMBER_BADGE_ID,MEMBER_ID
from MEMBERS
order by MEMBER_BADGE_ID
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this:

```
    DELETE FROM MEMBERS 
    WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM MEMBERS 
    group by MEMBER_BADGE_ID, MEMBER_ID 
    having count(*) >1)
```

Comment: Care to share why it won't work? I just tried it and it works.

Comment: This is a valid answer @VarunMehta. Result will be 
(3128, 859986, 2320) and  (2546, 860062, 1921)

Comment: If you're using GROUP BY in a query, all items in your SELECT statement must either be contained as part of an aggregate function, e.g. Sum() or Count() , else they will also need to be included in the GROUP BY clause. ... You need to use an Aggregate function and then group by any non-aggregated columns.

Comment: @VarunMehta Isn't MIN() an aggregate function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql